# Intersection of affine spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Take the following system: $Tx=a$ and $\langle b,x\rangle=C$ where T is a matrix
>   and $b \in V$ a vector space and $a,c$ are given. Then if we call
>   $S=\{x:Tx=0\}$ and $H=\{x: \langle b,x\rangle=0\}$. If the system has no solution
>   then $S \subset H$

It seems like a known linear algebra statement but I can't prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How can this be. Take two non intersecting lines.

Comment: Sorry, took out too much context. I'll edit the post

Comment: $C\in \mathbb{K}$ field?, $\langle , \rangle$ is a inner product?

Comment: $V$ is $\mathbb{R}$ ( or $\mathbb{C}$) vector space and is a inner product

Comment: Take $Tx= \langle b, x \rangle$ and $C \neq 0$. Now we have two parallel planes that do not intersect.

Answer (score 0):

It is false without further hypotheses.

*Counterexample*: Consider two non-intersecting affine lines in $3$-space. Their directing spaces $U$ and $V$ are vector lines (thus of the samedimension) which intersect only in the origin.

Comment: I took the problem way out of  context. It's edited with more context now